# azure machine learning- Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, module, machine-learning, azure-blob-storage, reader

How can i read Data from multiple files stored in Azure Blob storage  with azure machine learning studio "At once"?

I tried to use the Reader module and it's work just fine with one file, can it be useful for more than one, or do i have to look for an other solution ?

Thank you for your Help !

Answer (score 1):

If there are not so many blobs, you could just add multiple readers with each map to one of your input blobs. Then use modules under "Data Transformation" -> "Manipulation" to do things like "Add Rows" or "Join".

Answer (score 0):

Use a lot of readers which read from different blobs and then connect them to a MetaData Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Although the approach to use multiple `Reader` modules will work, it become wildly difficult when there are many inputs, or the number of inputs is varied.

Instead, you can use the `Execute Python Script` module to directly access blob storage. Doing so, however, is exceedingly painful if you've never done it before.  Here's are the issues:

1. The `azure.storage.blob` Python package is not loaded by default into Azure ML.  However, this can be created manually, or downloaded from the link below (correct version as of Feb 11, 2016).
2. The default usage of `azure.storage.blob.BlobService` uses HTTPS, which is not currently supported in Azure ML blob storage access. For this, you can pass in `protocol='http'` during the BlobService creation to force the use of HTTP: `client = BlobService(STORAGE_ACCOUNT, STORAGE_KEY, protocol="http")`

Here are the steps to get it working:

1. Download `azure.zip` which provides the required `azure.storage.*` libraries: https://azuremlpackagesupport.blob.core.windows.net/python/azure.zip
2. Upload them as a DataSet to the Azure ML Studio
3. Connect them to the Zip input on an `Execute Python Script` module, which is the 3rd input.
4. Write your script as you would normally, being sure to create your `BlobService` object with `protocol='http'`
5. Run the Experiment - you should now be able to read and write to blob storage.

Some example code can be found here: https://gist.github.com/drdarshan/92fff2a12ad9946892df

Here is the code to make it work for a single file. This can be extended to work with numerous files by accessing a container and filtering, but that will depend on your business logic.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobService

def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
    account_name = 'mystorageaccount'
    account_key='p8kSy3FACx...redacted...ebz3plQ=='
    container_name = "upload"

    blob_service = BlobService(account_name, account_key, protocol='http')

    file = blob_service.get_blob_to_text(container_name,'myfile.txt')
    # You can also get_blob_to_(bytes|file|path), if you need to do so.

    # Do stuff with your file here
    #   Logic, logic, logic

    # Execute Python Script requires that a dataframe is returned. It can be null.
    # Return value must be of a sequence of pandas.DataFrame
    return dataframe1,
```

For further information on limitations, why HTTP, and other notes, see [Access Azure blog storage from within an Azure ML experiment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246826/access-azure-blog-storage-from-within-an-azure-ml-experiment/35327300)