# Is it possible to import python scripts in Azure?

Tags: python, azure, cortana-intelligence, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a python script that is written in different files (one for importing, one for calculations, et cetera). These are all in the same folder, and when I need a function from another function I do something like

```
import file_import
file_import.do_something_usefull()
```

where, of course, in the `file_import` there is a function `do_something_usefull()` that, uhm, does something usefull. How can I accomplish the same in Azure?

Comment: you must tell in which service you want to use it - AWS, Automation, etc..

Comment: I have seriously no idea what you mean by that. It is the Machine Learning  environment. Is that sufficient?

Comment: Yes, I guess. Maybe you should explain more what you tried within Azure Machine Learning, and what issue you have encountered ?

Comment: I've got something like [this](http://imgur.com/HKdiB5u). I do not see an option to upload a python script or module to include it in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it out myself. It is documenten on Microsoft's site [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-execute-python-scripts/).

The steps, very short, are:

1. Include all the python you want in a .zip
2. Upload that zip as a dataset
3. Drag the dataset as the third option parameter in the 'execute python'-block (example below)

[image: Example dragging zip to Python script]

4. execute said function by importing `import Hello` (the name of the file, not the zip) and running `Hello.do_something_usefull()`

Answer (score 1):

As reference, there is a similiar answered thread you can refer to, please see [Access Azure blog storage from within an Azure ML experiment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246826/access-azure-blog-storage-from-within-an-azure-ml-experiment/35271122#35271122).