# Time out: Access Azure blob storage from within an Azure ML experiment

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, blob, azure-machine-learning-service

I would like to access azure blob storage from within an Azure ML experiment. I completely followed the answer from 
[Access Azure blog storage from within an Azure ML experiment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246826/access-azure-blog-storage-from-within-an-azure-ml-experiment)
however, there was some error.

My code is

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobService

def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
   dataframe1.to_csv("output.csv", index=True)
   account_name = "acount_name"
   account_key="rJfqPEFcbgpS...SKZrBs5J2eOq0IJYrc2Vg=="
   CONTAINER_NAME = "CONTAINER_NAME"

   blob_service = BlobService(account_name, account_key, protocol='http')
   blob_service.put_block_blob_from_path(CONTAINER_NAME,"output","output.csv")
```

The error log is blow

```
[Critical]     Error: Error 0085: The following error occurred during script 
evaluation, please view the output log for more information:
---------- Start of error message from Python interpreter ----------
Caught exception while executing function: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-
packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 559, in urlopen
body=body, headers=headers)
File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-
packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 353, in 
_make_request
conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
File "C:\pyhome\lib\http\client.py", line 1083, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "C:\pyhome\lib\http\client.py", line 1128, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body)
File "C:\pyhome\lib\http\client.py", line 1079, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
File "C:\pyhome\lib\http\client.py", line 911, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "C:\pyhome\lib\http\client.py", line 885, in send
self.sock.sendall(data)
socket.timeout: timed out
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 376, in send
timeout=timeout
File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-
packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 609, in urlopen
_stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", 
line 247, in increment
raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", 
line 309, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-
packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 559, in urlopen
body=body, headers=headers)
File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-
packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 353, in 
_make_request
conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
File "C:\pyhome\lib\http\client.py", line 1083, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "C:\pyhome\lib\http\client.py", line 1128, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body)
File "C:\pyhome\lib\http\client.py", line 1079, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
File "C:\pyhome\lib\http\client.py", line 911, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "C:\pyhome\lib\http\client.py", line 885, in send
self.sock.sendall(data)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', 
timeout('timed out',))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\server\invokepy.py", line 199, in batch
odfs = mod.azureml_main(*idfs)
File "C:\temp\a24f27b62ef74991b262bafe5e685164.py", line 39, in azureml_main
blob_service.put_block_blob_from_path(CONTAINER_NAME,"ppp","output.csv")
File "c:\temp\script bundle\azure\storage\blob\blobservice.py", line 975, in 
put_block_blob_from_path
retry_wait)
File "c:\temp\script bundle\azure\storage\blob\blobservice.py", line 1072, in 
put_block_blob_from_file
x_ms_lease_id)
File "c:\temp\script bundle\azure\storage\blob\blobservice.py", line 883, in 
put_blob
self._perform_request(request)
File "c:\temp\script bundle\azure\storage\storageclient.py", line 171, in 
_perform_request
resp = self._filter(request)
File "c:\temp\script bundle\azure\storage\storageclient.py", line 160, in 
_perform_request_worker
return self._httpclient.perform_request(request)
File "c:\temp\script bundle\azure\storage\_http\httpclient.py", line 181, in 
perform_request
self.send_request_body(connection, request.body)
File "c:\temp\script bundle\azure\storage\_http\httpclient.py", line 143, in 
send_request_body
connection.send(request_body)
File "c:\temp\script bundle\azure\storage\_http\requestsclient.py", line 81, 
in send
self.response = self.session.request(self.method, self.uri, data=request_body, 
headers=self.headers, timeout=self.timeout)
File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 468, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 576, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 426, in send
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', timeout('timed 
out',))
Process returned with non-zero exit code 1
```

Any help or thought is appreciated!

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Peter Pan.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue via copy your code and upload a dataset zip file include [azure python library](https://azuremlpackagesupport.blob.core.windows.net/python/azure.zip), but failed.

According to the error information, it seems to be just a network layer issue. Maybe try again later and it will works.

And per my experience, other suggestions as below.

1. Check your storage account whether enabled `Secure transfer required` option in the `Configuration` tab. If so, please remove the `protocol='http'` code or change to `https`.
2. According to the storage APIs you used, it's the old version `0.20.3` of Azure Storage Python SDK. You can upload a dataset zip file include new version `0.34.3` instead of the old one to try again.

Hope it helps.